# How can I implement retina Map Labels for Google Maps

Tags: javascript, google-maps, canvas

[Here is a CodePen demo](https://codepen.io/JayGeorge/pen/GmoQYG) where I have a polygon displayed on a Google Map, along with a label on top of it using the "Map Labels" library.

Everything is working great except I cannot get the label text to render the correct resolution for retina screens.

**How can I get the Map Labels text to display for HiDPI screens in the context of my demo?**

There seems to be a known solution [here](https://github.com/googlemaps/js-map-label/issues/3) but I can't figure out how to implement the function in my demo. This is probably because my knowledge of JS is limited. I'm sure someone else could point out what to do in a jiffy.

Here is a preview of my code, but it's better to check the [CodePen demo](https://codepen.io/JayGeorge/pen/GmoQYG):

```
/* GROUP MAP / STAGE / MAP LABEL
=================================================== */
/* Reference: https://googlemaps.github.io/js-map-label/docs/reference.html */
var mapLabel = new MapLabel({
  text: 'Main Stage',
  position: new google.maps.LatLng(51.420118, -0.064973),
  map: map,
  fontSize: 15,
  fontColor: "#9c0058",
  align: 'left',
});
mapLabel.set('position', new google.maps.LatLng(51.420118, -0.064973));
```

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve this by adding the following code directly to the plugin at the point in which the canvas is being created:

`.a=document.createElement("canvas");a.width=500;a.height=500;a.style.width="250px";a.style.height="250px";a.getContext('2d').scale(2,2);`

I've updated my CodePen so you can see this working.